# How to remove duplicates from JSONArray

Tags: javascript, set

I have an array that looks like below:

```
{
    "instances":[
    {
      "Instances":"1",
      "riskdesc":"Low",
      "alert":"X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing",
      "OtherInformation":"T",
      "Method":"GET"
    },
    {
      "Instances":"1",
      "riskdesc":"High",
      "alert":"Cookie No HttpOnly Flag",
      "OtherInformation":"T",
      "Method":"GET"
    },
    {
      "Instances":"1",
      "riskdesc":"Low",
      "alert":"X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing",
      "OtherInformation":"T",
      "Method":"GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

Ultimately, I need a unique alert value from each object and their corresponding riskdesc and to eliminate the duplicates alert values.

I may be doing about this wrong, so if there is an easier way to accomplish that end goal, I am open to ideas

Please find the desired output below.

[image]

Comment: *"... may be doing about this wrong"*, ... *"easier way"*, how should we know this? please add your code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const instances = [
{
"Instances":"1",
"riskdesc":"Low",
"alert":"X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing",
"OtherInformation":"T",
"Method":"GET"
},
{
"Instances":"1",
"riskdesc":"High",
"alert":"Cookie No HttpOnly Flag",
"OtherInformation":"T",
"Method":"GET"
},
{
"Instances":"1",
"riskdesc":"Low",
"alert":"X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing",
"OtherInformation":"T",
"Method":"GET"
}
]

const unique = instances.reduce((acc, curr) =>  (acc.some((i) => i.alert === curr.alert)) ? acc : acc.concat([curr]), [])
```

Comment: It worked like charm. I also would need the number of occurrences . Here the "X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing" occurrence is 2. Is there anyway to take the duplicate occurrences count.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest thing I can think of is to use a `key/value array,` ask if `key` already exists and move along. The `key` would have to be the value that you don't want duplicated, so it would be the value of `alert` for each instance.

Cons of this? Well, you'd have the **alerts** value duplicated, once as a key of the `key/value array` and once as a value inside of it.

```js
const instances = [{
    "Instances": "1",
    "riskdesc": "Low",
    "alert": "X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing",
    "OtherInformation": "T",
    "Method": "GET"
  },
  {
    "Instances": "1",
    "riskdesc": "High",
    "alert": "Cookie No HttpOnly Flag",
    "OtherInformation": "T",
    "Method": "GET"
  },
  {
    "Instances": "1",
    "riskdesc": "Low",
    "alert": "X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing",
    "OtherInformation": "T",
    "Method": "GET"
  }
];

let non_duplicates_instances = {};
for(let i=0; i<instances.length; ++i){
  const instance = instances[i];
  if( !(instance.alert in non_duplicates_instances) ){
    non_duplicates_instances[instance.alert] = instance;
  }
}

console.log(non_duplicates_instances);
```